# Si no existe un elemento del DOM, que lo cree (JQuery / Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Realizo la comprobación de si existe o no un elemento con jQuery por su id, pero me lanza error. Esta comprobación la realizo en un callback dentro de la instancia de un elemento. Necesito hacer esa comprobación ahí, ya que es el punto en el que recoge los datos y los debe guardar en un input hidden. pero si ese input ya existe, no necesito que se cree.

Este proceso se repite porque hay una subida de varias imágenes, pero el dato solo quiero que lo guarde una vez.

Este es mi código:

```
var capturaCam = new Camera(
        document.getElementById("camera-capt"),
        function (dataUrl) {

            var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataUrl);
            var fileInfo = getFileInfoFromBlob(blob);
            camsFiles.push(blob);
            processImage(fileInfo);

            var img_width = Camera.imagen.imgWidth;

            if ( $("#img_width").length == 0 ) { //Si no existe
                //crea el input hidden
                jQuery("#form-hidden").append("<input type='hidden' id='img_width' name='jform[img_width]' value='"+ img_width +"' data-hj-masked />");
            }
        }
    );
```

El error que muestra es:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
at Camera.verifiedPhoto (cameraconst.js:427)
at Camera.onAccept (cameraconst.js:436)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (Camera.js:676)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:4)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:4)
```

Me imagino que tiene que ver con algún conflicto con otro métodos por realizar esto dentro de la instancia. ¿Hay alguna otra manera de comprobar si existe el input hidden o corregir este error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función que selector de Jquery por id lo que hará sera devolverte un objeto Jquery que contiene una lista vacía de elementos (cuando no encuentre ningún elemento que coincida con ese id) o un elemento DOM si lo encuentra. Por ello es una  de la soluciones usar la propiedad **length** para saber si es  **null** o no. Para este caso probé con un ejemplo que la función la lee correctamente y ademas use una extensión para hacer mas atendible la función  **exists** y no me da ningún problema. Teniendo en cuenta eso  lo mas probable es que no se este cargando tu referencia de Jquery o sino tienes conflicto de nombres de otras referencias de javascript en tu proyecto (algún archivo usa $ como variable y $ es un alias para Jquery por eso te devuelve null reference ) , trata de revisar eso y de ser así usa **jQuery.noConflict()** para corregirlo siguiendo los pasos [Aqui](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) de la misma documentación.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<form id="form-hidden">
<label>Nombre </label>
<input id="nombre" name="">
<br>
</form>
<button onclick="ValidaImg()">Valida Imagen</button>
<script>
$.fn.exists = function () {
    return this.length !== 0;
}
function ValidaImg(){
debugger;
var img_width ="value";
if(!$("#img_width").exists()) 
   $("#form-hidden").append("<input type='text' id='img_width' name='jform[img_width]' value='"+ img_width +"' data-hj-masked />");


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```